# How do I add Opan Sans .tff using CSS?

Tags: html, css, web, fonts, webfonts

I want to use the OpenSans-Light.tff webfont that I downloaded off of Google Fonts. Here is what I am trying within my main.css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:"OpenSans";
    src: url("fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf");
}

.banner h1 {
    font-family: "OpanSans", arial;
}
```

Though it's not working.

Comment: first, it is OPEN, not OPAN. Second, that is not the code provided by Google fonts, not even close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use just `@import` use it like this:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
```

or add this to your HTML `<head>`

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and then add this to your CSS

```
.banner h1{font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (and arguably best way to do it) is simply use `@import` in your CSS.

Here's a JSFiddle I made for you: **http://jsfiddle.net/gLej4h82/**

CSS:

```
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,300);

to the very top of your code in your css file and reference it on the certain object like the below it should work

```
.banner h1{
font-family:'Open Sans', sans serif;
font-weight: 400; /* 400 is regular, 300 is light, 700 is bold */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this service to generate the font face for you its very nice service.

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator